How to find the equation of an ellipse using three points?
I came across this interesting problem yesterday and I am not quite able to find the equation of the ellipse after it has performed that roll. The original problem shows the ellipse to rotate till it is tangent to the x-axis at $(5,0)$ and that animation also shows the ellipse passing through two more points roughly speaking; $(0,7.9)$ and $(0.3.5)$.
To summarize, I require the equation of the rotated ellipse, knowing we have three points $(5,0)$, $(0,7.9)$ and $(0.3.5)$ and the fact that the ellipse is tangent to x-axis at $(5,0)$.
I have tried using  $\frac{(x-x_0)^2}{a^2}+\frac{(y-y_0)^2}{b^2}=1$ as a standard equation (with 4 unknowns) ,but this just represents an ellipse with its axes parallel to coordinate axes so this was a dead end.
I am interested to understand how to write this ellipse's equation.

Why don't you write the equations first ?

$\dfrac{x^2}{5^2} + \dfrac{(y - 2)^2}{2^2} = 1$ or $\dfrac{x^2}{5^2}+\dfrac{y^2}{2^2}-y=0.$ All the images can be written uniquely in the form $ax^2+bxy+cy^2-y=0$ and the one we seek goes through $(5,0),$ has major axis 5 and minor axis 2 and has eccentricity $\frac{\sqrt{21}}5.$ I don’t have the time now, but this seems tractable.

You definitely need another point (or another tangent) to construct the ellipse.

@Intelligentipauca Hmm. I interpreted it to be about the specific $a=5, b=2$ ellipse rotated so that it’s always tangent to the $x$-axis, and believed the three implied points mentioned to be incidental. What am I missing?

@Jan-MagnusØkland You are right: I had not considered that the lengths of axes are given.

Technically, you can't. The general equation for a conic section is
$Ax^2+By^2+Cxy+Dx+Ey+F=0$.
You need as many constraints as unknowns to uniquely determine a conic.
Three points won't do it, however in that problem the slope of the tangent line at a point on the curve is given. That' a 4th constraint. Further, the rotation leaves the semi major and semi minor axes unchanged. That adds another two constraints. So there is actually more information than is at first apparent.
I put an answer to that scenario in the linked question.

I think this is an answer to the linked question, rather than to this one.

I think you're right. I moved it there and will answer this one differently.

Thank you for this, did not expect the use of elliptical functions :)

I have the feeling that your problem is ill-posed. You can also find a non-rotated ellipse that passes through your 3 points and the horizontal tangent constraint. The result shown above can be found by imposing an horizontal tangent at (0,8)
